# Can not build javafx application under java 9 targeting java 8

Tags: java, javafx-8, javac, java-9

I am trying to build an application which has a GUI built with JavaFX and targeting java 8 with java 9's new release flag.

Compiling

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String... args) {

    }
}
```

when targeting java 9 with

```
javac Testing.java
```

works fine (also when using `--release 9`), but when I add the release flag

```
javac --release 8 Testing.java
```

it fails to compile giving *does not exist* errors

```
Testing.java:1:error: package javafx.application does not exist
```

There is no problem when compiling this under a JDK8 javac.  I've tried using the `--add-modules` flag to add the jfx modules, but that flag is not allowed when setting a release to 8.

Is there a way to make this work under java 9?  It seems that it doesn't think that the jfx packages are included with java 8, but they are (at least in oracle's release).

I am using the release version of java 9 on Windows, and have built the same application without problems under the most recent java 8 release.

---

I have tried to add the **jfxrt.jar** from my java 8 installation (and not **rt.jar**) to the classpath while compiling with the `--release 8` flag, and it does work.

My understanding is that one purpose of the release flag was to remove the need to have multiple versions of the JDK installed (or at least their **rt.jar** files).  I'm not sure if the intent was to only remove the need to compile against this one file, or if the intent was to remove the need to compile against any JDK packaged files (and **jfxrt.jar** is included with JDK8 [at least in Oracle's version] requiring no special flags or classpath modifications to use it).

Without being certain of the intent, it somehow seems wrong that something would compile perfectly under java 8 but would require an additional jar to compile (and only compile not run) under java 9 targeting java 8 (but not when targeting java 9), and thus requiring multiple JDKs.  For anyone more familiar with the intended implementation of the release flag, should this be working this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour seems strange though in terms of how the `--release` flag internally resolved the required jdk internal classes. But owing to the fact that *rt.jars are removed in JDK9 and that `javafx.application` was a part of `jfxrt.jar`, it could be a probable reason why the same would complain about the missing package.

---

The compiling section from [migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-77874D97-46F3-4DB5-85E4-2ACB5F8D760B) though details this out that the `--release N` flag is conceptually a macro for:

```
-source N -target N -bootclasspath $PATH_TO_rt.jar_FOR_RELEASE_N
```

Hence it should work, if you try something like this for sure:

```
javac -source 8 -target 8 -bootclasspath some/path/to/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar Testing.java
```

---

A simple solution in the replacement of above, of course, is to add the `jfxrt.jar` file to the classpath and then compile using the `--release 8` flag.

---

<sub>**Note**: Still leaves me puzzled why `--release` won't find the previous versions `rt.jar`? -- Might want to check for any such reported bugs.</sub>

<sub>**From comments**:- JavaFX is [considered an included extension](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-October/005994.html) in Java 8, so is not resolved when targeting version 8. Only the classes that would have been in the rt.jar file are resolved.</sub>

Comment: It does compile (with the `--release 8` flag), if I add the jfxrt.jar file to the classpath.  However, this does not seem quite right to me.  My understanding is that one goal of the new --release flag is to eliminate the need to have multiple java versions install (which is not easy to get working with Window), and that the compiler would handle resolving everything correctly.  I understand that anything that compiles under 8 should compile under 9.  I guess it does, but not while targeting 8.  I would expect that it would not require additional flags if it didn't in 8 (except for EE mods).

Comment: It also now requires my build files to be sensitive to my particular system setup (I am building the real application with Gradle, but removed this from my question, because the problem has nothing to do with Gradle).  This is really undesireable.

Comment: Where would I go to check on/make a bug report for this (assuming it is a bug)?  Is there a separate process for Oracle versus OpenJDK?

Comment: @Matthew I would recommend querying this on repective [dev-mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo) and by that time wait for a response from officials here as well in terms of what exactly is the implementation of the release flag.

Comment: I posted to the mailing list, and received an answer.  JavaFX is considered an included extension in Java 8, so is not resolved when targeting version 8.  Only the classes that would have been in the rt.jar file are resolved.

Comment: Here is the link to the mailing list thread where this was answered: [http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-October/005993.html](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-October/005993.html)

Comment: @Matthew Thanks, linked with the edited part of the answer.